# Translation of a particle vortex in OpenGL Shader

Tags: opengl, grid, particles

the issue is very vague, I know. I guess it is more of a logical question.

I am working on some grid and particle hybrid system and I want to implement a vortex with a few spread particles that are positioned in a grid. The items in the grid contain values between -1.0 and 1.0.

Super simple, I let the grid spin in a vortex by setting my vector field values to v = {y, -x}

Hurray, they spin. Now, I want to move my vortex somewhere. I get weird results. So I simplified the whole thing, do not use the vortex now and just move my grid. I can change my initial values, of course, and the grid is moved. If I spin the grid all particles still move around (0,0) which is still in the center of the grid, e.g. it spins not around its center, but like around its right corner.

I translate the grid inside my computer shader to the center, spin, and translate back. So it should work, but this gives me a weeeeeird behaviour. "Some" particles move to the left bottom corner. F

The simple code of my compute shader for what is happening in the last picture is this: (vertex shader only sends the gridVortex values to the fragment shader)

```
void main()
{
    uint INDEX = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;

    gridVortex[INDEX].xy += 0.0002f;
    gridVortex[INDEX].xy -= 0.0002f;
}
```

As you can see I just move each particle by 0.0002 and back without anything else. The expected result would be seeing no difference. SM knows, why. Maybe you have a hint for me? :-)

[image: The Grid] [image: Spinning Vortex][image: Only translate and restranslate]

Comment: Maybe you're not properly synchronizing things? Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Something at least is messing up the compute shader. I copied the code to the vertex shader and everything is smooth. Giving that, your theory about some sync issue seems to be correct. I will try to wrap a tiny MCVE together.